# How to set a projection matrix on Three.js which does this kind of mapping?

Tags: matrix, 3d, three.js, projection-matrix

How to make a projection matrix on Three.js which does the mapping from 3d points to screen coordinates described by the rule below?

```
screen_x = x - z*0.5
screen_y = y - z*0.5
depth = z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection matrix represents the following equations:

```
xx xy xz xt    <- x' = (xx*x + xy*y + xz*z + xt) / (wx*x + wy*y + wz*z + 1)
yx yy yz yt       y' = (yx*x + yy*y + yz*z + yt) / (wx*x + wy*y + wz*z + 1)
zx zy zz zt       z' = (zx*x + zy*y + zz*z + zt) / (wx*x + wy*y + wz*z + 1)
wx wy wz  1
```

From that all the other elements will be zero, but

```
screen_x = x-z*0.5 : xx=1,       xz=-0.5
screen_y = y-z*0.5 :       yy=1, xz=-0.5
depth  z'= z       :             zz=1      (and ww=1)
```

**EDIT** This not the general projection matrix, but only applicable to this particular problem.

The general [symmetric] projection matrix is of form

```
 a  0  0  d 
 0  b  0  e  
 0  0  c  f 
 0  0  1  0,
```

from which it follows that x and y will be divided by wx*z == z.

Comment: Thank you (that's what I've been trying, but I just figured I was using the wrong renderer, which didn't implement z-buffer). I'm glad to actually understand what's going on, though. What's an interpretation for the wx wy and wz values? Also, I guess you got something wrong: the last element ("1") here actually works for scaling the whole result, as I found by experimentation.

Comment: There's no interpretation of wx,wy,wz values alone, but row0+-row3 represents the plane equation of left/right clip planes. row1+-row3 := equations of top/bottom planes and row2+-row3 are the equations of near/far clip planes of the viewing frustum. As a whole (x y z 1) * persp_Matrix transforms the viewing frustum (clipped pyramid) to _unit cube_. conversely a single vector-matrix multiplication tells if a point is outside or inside the view.

Comment: One can scale by modifying the ww-term -- but only when the xt,yt,zt vector is zero. The universally correct way is to multiply the upper 3x3 vector of the ViewMatrix and then multiply the result with the (fairly sparse) projection matrix. (Once multiplied I think the scaling "scatters" all around the VP -matrix and it can't be located absolutely only on the top-left corner, I presume)